# Pageviews per country per month in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I want to plot pageviews per country and per month in google analytics so I have a result like this:

```
Month / Country / Pageviews
October 2014 / Germany / 45.554
October 2014 / Russia / 32.435
...
November 2014 / Germany / 48.453
November 2014 / Russia / 33.786
...
```

I have tried this:
Audience -> Overview I have selected a long period and plot per month. Then I can get a country breakdown for that period but not per month.
Also it looks like I can only retrieve "Sessions" and not "pageviews" per country. Also in the detailed report, pageviews does not even show up.

So I tried this crazy workaround:
Behavior -> Site Content -> Content Drilldown
In the table below I have selected "country" in the 2nd dimension. Now I see each content drilldown per country and I also see the pageview. But I cannot group it per month. So I could now sort by countries, show all rows (a few thousend) and export via Excel to group countries together to have the pageviews per country in that period. I would have to repeat that for every month I want to look at -> lot of work.

Is there an easier solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried creating a custom report?

In your GA account, go to *Customization*, and then put in your metrics and dimensions.

[image]

Then click, *Save*.

You'll now have a custom report that you can email to yourself every month.